# PHP - login to a remote server, trough my own server, with HTTPS, cookies and proxy, and downloading the html

Tags: php, cookies, ssl, curl, https

so what i am trying to do is this:

- login to the other server with a PHP on my own server (either with my username and pass/or with my cookies)
- then have access to the page i want to display/download

i want to write a PHP script that is located on my own server, that automatically does a login to another server, that uses HTTPS and a web form for login.
after the login i have access to that page that i am trying to download.
i dont know if it would be possible to login and download the html only with the cookies that i have in my browser through a previous login, or if i need to do the login in my php script through some https login method.
can i do any of this with curl or fsocksopen or what would be the best way to realize this?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to try. in most cases you should be fine if you export your cookies and use them in your curl request.

however the website mave hashed the cookies with the remote address, or given a timeout on them.

then you probably have to login from the server. with php / curl you can do that all.

the only thing that may be a problem is javascript/captcha codes.

in addition you should definately check [zend http client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/zend.http.client.advanced.html), it has functionalities that makes "browsing" easy. for example saving cookies and automatically passing them on in the next request and also deleting them if the server tells you so etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PEAR HTTP Request](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request.basic-auth.php) class.